# Pointers to buffer in IOCTL call

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby and bit-struct to configure my network interfaces in a test setup. This works fine for most IOCTL calls, but I can not figure out how to call SIOCGIFCONF

Here is an example:

If I want to get the MAC address of an interface I would write something like this:

```
class LinuxIfreqMacAddr < BitStruct
  char       :name,    128
  unsigned   :type,     16, :endian => :native
  hex_octets :macaddr,  48
  pad        :padding,  64
end

ifr = LinuxIfreqMacAddr.new
ifr.name = "eth0"
s.ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR, ifr) # s is a socket
puts ifr.macaddr
```

This works fine, and will print the MAC address of eth0. But the signiture of "struct ifconf" (used with SIOCGIFCONF) requires to pass along a buffer.

Here is the signature:

```
struct ifconf  {
    int     ifc_len;
    char __user *ifcu_buf;
};
```

How can I from ruby call the SIOCGIFCONF ioctl command with a buffer of 4096 bytes?

Answer (score 4):

Use the "P" specifier of [Array#pack](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/pack) to store a pointer to a
buffer:

```
require 'socket'
sock = UDPSocket.new
ifreqs = ' ' * 4096
ifconf = [ifreqs.size, ifreqs].pack("l!P")
SIOCGIFCONF = 0x8912
sock.ioctl(SIOCGIFCONF, ifconf)
data_size = ifconf.unpack('l!').first
p data_size # => 120
```

## How this works

Create the buffer into which ioctl will store the array of interface information:

```
ifreqs = ' ' * 4096
```

Now create a second buffer to pass to the ioctl call.  The buffer will be a string that represents the [*ifconf* struct](http://linux.die.net/man/7/netdevice):

```c
struct ifconf {
    int                 ifc_len; /* size of buffer */
    union {
        char           *ifc_buf; /* buffer address */
        struct ifreq   *ifc_req; /* array of structures */
    };
};
```

We use [Array#pack](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/pack) to do it:

```
ifconf = [ifreqs.size, ifreqs].pack("l!P")
```

The format specifier breaks down into:

- "l!" - A signed long of the platform's native size.  This encodes `ifreqs.size`.
- "P" - A pointer to a fixed length buffer.  This encodes the address
  of the buffer stored in the `ifreqs` string.

Now we can make our call:

```
SIOCGIFCONF = 0x8912
sock.ioctl(SIOCGIFCONF, ifconf)
```

The SIOCGIFCONF call modifies the ifconf buffer, updating `ifc_len` to be the
number of bytes of data actually stored in the `ifreqs` bufffer.  We
can see that by unpacking just that element of the array:

```
data_size = ifconf.unpack('l!').first
p data_size # => 120
```

Decoding the data stored into *ifreqs* is left as an exercise for the
reader.